# How to access WAMP from local network

Tags: php, web, wamp

I have a website installed on a localhost WAMP, so I need to access it from another connected through LAN or Wi-Fi on the same network.

I want to access the information on the localhost website on another PC which is also connected on the same local network. So how can I do this?

I have tried installing on a free hosting site, but it doesn't create. Let me install it as I don't know the database hostname of that web hosting service.

Comment: Dont use `localhost` use the real `IP Address` in the browser, that should work in local network.

Comment: Also take care to open port 80 if that MS-Windows system is running a local firewall. Or deactivate the firewall completely for a test.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the IP address of your system, where your project is installed. Instead of localhost then you have to connect with LAN to your other system.

Then type your IP Address followed by your project name. You will see your project on the other system.

Comment: okay then but  do i need to setup  the website on every computer because it uses a database and i want to use the same database in every pc connected on local network and also what is the db hostname in infinity server

Comment: Yes Karan Rustagi, you have to setup the website on every computer and database will be only in one computer, and database host name will be the IP address of database system

Comment: yeah i figured it out it is working good for now

Comment: Thanks, Karan Rustagi, You are most welcome.